# Compiling executable with "-fPIC" flag (no shared library)

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile, fpic

I am currently working on some legacy packages and I see that some `Makefile`s use the `-fPIC` flag to compile the final executable.

My understanding is that this is used when creating a shared library and that it would make no sense to use it when creating an executable.

I wonder if I am right or I am missing something, because when I search on the internet, I only get results talking about shared libraries and not executables.

Thanks,

Comment: Check Wikipedia for possible reasons: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Position independent code can be useful outside of shared library context. One common case is [Address space layout randomization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization), which makes the final executable more secure against code injection attacks.

In several distributions, such as [Fedora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fedora_%28operating_system%29), most of the packages are built as PIE.

Comment: Thanks! That is very interesting, although the makefile of the application I am having a look to is not really that sensitive (small test app), so I think that they just added that flag by mistake :) (e.g. copy-paste)

Comment: Theoretically, that flag could be useful on some architectures which otherwise would default to position-dependent code but fail to link for some reason.

Comment: Doens't explain -fPIC, only -fPIE.

Answer (score 2):

It might be used to build position independent executables which can lead to better security thanks to ASRL. However, you should use instead `-fpie` and `-pie`:

```
cc -c -fpie foo.c -o foo.o
cc    -pie  foo.o -o foo
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll have a look to that flag too, although I think that the package doesn't really need that feature.